# How to find duplicate values in mongodb using distinct query?

Tags: node.js, mongodb, distinct-values

I am working on Mongodb distinct query, i have one collection with repeated entry, i am doing as per the created_at. But i want to fetch without repeated values.

Sample JSON

```
{
  "posts": [{
      "id": "580a2eb915a0161010c2a562",
      "name": "\"Ah Me Joy\" Porter",
      "created_at": "15-10-2016"
    }, {
      "id": "580a2eb915a0161010c2a562",
      "name": "\"Ah Me Joy\" Porter",
      "created_at": "25-10-2016"
    }, {
      "id": "580a2eb915a0161010c2a562",
      "name": "\"Ah Me Joy\" Porter",
      "created_at": "01-10-2016"
    }, {
      "id": "580a2eb915a0161010c2bf572",
      "name": "Hello All",
      "created_at": "05-10-2016"
   }]
}
```

Mongodb Query

```
db.getCollection('posts').find({"id" : ObjectId("580a2eb915a0161010c2a562")})
```

So i want to know about distinct query of mongodb, please kindly go through my post and let me know.

Comment: What do you mean by finding distinct?

Comment: @hyades so when i'll do db.collection.find it won't fetch the repeated values, it will ignore the repeated values and show only unique results...

Comment: You collection has multiple entries for the `id`. If you want only one you can try `findOne`, which would choose any random one

Comment: @hyades No i want to do like this db.posts.find({}), i want to eliminate the duplicates values and populate the results.

Comment: With the above sample JSON as the example, can you update your question through the [edit] link and show us what your expected JSON result should be from the query?

Answer (score 0):

try as follows:

```
db.getCollection('posts').distinct("id")
```

It will return all the unique IDs in the collection `posts` as follows:

```
["580a2eb915a0161010c2a562", "580a2eb915a0161010c2bf572"]
```

From MongoDB docs:

The example use the `inventory` collection that contains the following documents:

```
 { "_id": 1, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "111", "color": "red" }, "sizes": [ "S", "M" ] }
{ "_id": 2, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "111", "color": "blue" }, "sizes": [ "M", "L" ] }
{ "_id": 3, "dept": "B", "item": { "sku": "222", "color": "blue" }, "sizes": "S" }
{ "_id": 4, "dept": "A", "item": { "sku": "333", "color": "black" }, "sizes": [ "S" ] }
```

To Return Distinct Values for a Field (`dept`):

```
db.inventory.distinct( "dept" )
```

The method returns the following array of distinct dept values:

```
[ "A", "B" ]
```

Reference:

1. https://docs.mongodb.com/v3.2/reference/method/db.collection.distinct/

Answer (score 0):

As per my understanding, you want to get distinct results which should eliminates the duplicate `id` in that collection

By using distinct in mongodb, It will return list of distinct values

```
db.getCollection('posts').distinct("id"); 
["580a2eb915a0161010c2a562", "580a2eb915a0161010c2bf572"]
```

So you should look into mongodb aggregation

```
db.posts.aggregate(
{ "$group" : { "_id" : "$id", "name" : {"$first" : "$name"}, "created_at" : {"$first" : "$created_at"} }}
)
```

The output will be list of results which eliminates the duplicate `id` documents